# how to convert www.example.com/posts/123 to example.com/posts/123?

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, nginx, no-www

I am using nginx 1.2.1 running in Ubuntu 12.10

I have followed the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7958540/80353

So my vhosts now look like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 5M;
        server_name example.com;
        root /var/virtual/example.com/webroot;
        include common.conf;
        include php.conf;
}
```

Not sure what I did wrong.

Currently, whenever I do a `www.example.com/posts/123`, I get 302 to `example.com`

I was expecting `example.com/posts/123`

UPDATE:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 5M;
        server_name example.com;
        root /var/virtual/example.com/webroot;
        include common.conf;
        include php.conf;
}
```

common.conf is:

```
index index.html;

location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
}
```

cakephp.conf is:

```
include php.conf;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        expires max;
        access_log off;
}
```

php.conf is:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
}

index index.php;
```

Comment: The first settings seem fine, so you either didn't restart/reload nginx, or you somehow have another virtual host that captures these requests.